# Retrieve timestamp 12 of may 2018, 15:59:56 UTC-5 from firebase to android

Tags: android, firebase

I´m trying to retrieve field date : 12 of may 2018, 15:59:56 UTC-5 from firebase to my Android Class

Edited : I´m using firestore the field is timestamp
is saved as value date : 12 of may 2018, 15:59:56 UTC-5

I call data in this way

```
 currentUserId = auth!!.currentUser!!.uid

    database!!.collection(BRANCHES.USERS)
            .document(currentUserId)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                try {
                    user = it.toObject(UserUpdated::class.java)
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user.dateOfBirthday.toString())){
                        etUserBirthday?.setText("")
                    } else {                         etUserBirthday?.setText(convertTime(user.dateOfBirthday as Long))
                    }
                } catch (n : NullPointerException){
                    n.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                it.localizedMessage
            }
```

this is the class UserUpdated and fields with set and get

```
public class UserUpdated{
private Date dateOfBirthday;

public UserUpdated(){}

    public Date getDateOfBirthday() {
    return dateOfBirthday;
}

public void setDateOfBirthday(Date dateOfBirthday) {
    this.dateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday;
}}
```

when retrieve the data it read the field date from firebase but i get null on setDateOfBirthday and can´t show the date, is there an error on retrieving field date? can anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific.  Are you using Realtime Database or Firestore?  What is your code that makes the query? What is your database structure like?

Comment: post your database structure, also, you should first check with a Log if you get any values in your getDate , and then you will know if thats null or not

Comment: I updated, thanks for replys!